# Add v-bind:class programmatically

Tags: vuejs2

To add a class programmatically, I can use something like this:

```
this.$refs.mycells[123].classList.add('my-class')
```

But, how can I add a v-bind class like this programmatically ?

```
v-bind:class="{ active: radio == 'link'}"
```

Comment: The [documentation](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html) covers it pretty much. And particularly for above use case you could do: `v-bind:class="[{ active: radio === 'link' }]"`

Comment: I think there's a fairly major conceptual misunderstanding here. The template syntax looks a lot like HTML but that is just for convenience. In a template, both `class` and `v-bind:class` provide ways to tell Vue to generate a DOM node with a given class. They are effectively instructions to Vue, telling it what to generate. You can't add these instructions directly to the resulting DOM node. Sure you can (but shouldn't) muck around with the resulting DOM node but don't confuse the attributes/properties of the DOM node with the instructions Vue used to generate it in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can add class like object programatically, just declare a data reactive properties names "cssClass"

```
data: {
  cssClass: {
    active: true,
    'text-danger': false
  }
},
```

> There are two ways you can change using some event trigger methods or
>   computed properties, when dependent data changes, it updates the value

```
<div v-bind:class="cssClass">
<button v-on:click="onButtonClick"></button>
</div>

methods: {
 onButtonClick() { // if you want ro trigger from 
   // you can manipulate object
   this.cssClass = { active: false, 'text-danger': true }
 },
}
```

> Using computed:

```
<div v-bind:class="setCssClass(true)"></div>

computed: {
  setCssClass(val) {
    if (val == true) return { active: false, 'text-danger': true };
    return { active: false, 'text-danger': true };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can bind classes directly in the element or call a function to place appropriate classes.

```
 <p v-bind:class="user.role === 'admin' ? 'is_admin' : 'is_user'"></p>
```

The same logic can be placed into a function like shown below

```
  <p :class="placeAppropriateClass(user.role)"></p>
```

//

```
 methods:{
     placeAppropriateClass(role){
        let addClass = ''; 
        if(role === 'admin'){
            addClass = 'is_admin';
        }else if(role === 'user'){
            addClass = 'is_user';
        }else{
            addClass='is_guest';
        }
        return addClass;
     }
 }
```

This will add class to p tag according to a conditional statement.

```
 <p class="is_admin"></p>
```